# "set" and Environment variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, powershell, environment-variables

"I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.11. I want to display the environment variables and create a new one. However, I believe the process might be slightly different on Windows. When I enter 'set' in the command prompt, it works fine and shows the environment variables. But when I do the same in PyCharm's terminal, it displays the following message: 'cmdlet Set-Variable at command pipeline position 1 \nSupply values for the following parameters: Name[0]:' I would appreciate it if someone could help me with this."

Comment: Is this a Python question, a PowerShell question, or a PyCharm question?